# Hash Table Collision in pseudo code?

Tags: java, hashtable, collision

I've recently taken a test and I came across a problem regarding hash tables and collisions. I just wildly took a guess, and I got it right. Now I'm wondering why I got this particular question right.

[image: problem]

I have checked out other questions and they've utilized this equation to solve:

> n - m * (1 - ((m-1)/m)^n)

Can someone explain this?

*This problem is java based* if that helps!

Comment: Please don't post text in a screenshot. Post text as text.

Comment: You have a typo in the formula.  
Read here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem